# Address of dereferenced pointer construct

Tags: c, pointers, syntax, dereference, addressof

In **unqlite** c library I found following code:

```
 pObj = jx9VmReserveMemObj(&(*pVm),&nIdx);
```

where `pVm` is:

```
typedef struct jx9_vm jx9_vm;
jx9_vm *pVm
```

and function called is declared as:

```
jx9_value * jx9VmReserveMemObj(jx9_vm *, sxu32 *);
```

What for construct `&(*pVm)` is used in call instead of just `pVm`? Is `&(*pVm)` equivalent to `pVm`?

Comment: I can see no reason to use `&(*pVm)` over `pVm`.

Comment: @haccks I mentioned (a generic) one in my answer. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.3.2, *Address and indirection operators*

> [...] If the operand is the result of a unary `*` operator,
>   **neither that operator nor the `&` operator is evaluated and the result is as if both were
>   omitted**, except that the constraints on the operators still apply **and the result is not an lvalue.** [...]

So, **yes**, they are *equivalent*.

This construct can be used, however, to check the type of the argument against a pointer type. From the property of unary `*` operator,

> The operand of the unary `*` operator shall have pointer type.

So, the construct `&(*pVm)`

- will be fine, if `pvm` is a pointer or array name.
- will generate compiler error, if `pvm` is a non-pointer type variable.

See [the other answer by Alter Mann](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38915350/2173917) for code-wise example.

One more difference (*in general*) is, `pVm` can be *assigned* (can be used as LHS of the assignment operator), but `&(*pVm)` cannot.

Comment: "*So, the difference ...*" which does not matter in the context of the OP's example.

Comment: @alk Very well, but there _maybe_ other usage and _this_ particular usage can be to keep the coding standard uniform for that project. Added the required disclaimer, though. ;)

Answer (score 6):

> Is `&(*pVm)` equivalent to `pVm`?

Yes. <sup>*1</sup>

Same for `*(&pVm)`.

---

<sup><sup>**(*1)**</sup>
As the `*`-operator (*de-referencing*) only is applicable to pointers, the former construct only works on a pointer (or an array, which would decay to a pointer to its 1st element). The latter can be applied to any type of variable.</sup>:

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they are the same, but notice that it fails when the object is not an array or a pointer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct t {
    int value;
};

typedef struct t t;

int func(t *ptr)
{
    return ptr->value;
}

int main(void)
{
    t o = {.value = 0};
    t v[2] = {{.value = 1}, {.value = 2}};

    printf("%d\n", func(&(*o))); /* error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ */
    printf("%d\n", func(&(*v))); /* WORKS */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sir, hope you won't mind me putting a link to your answer into mine. :)

Comment: No problem Sourav ;)