# How to convert array pointer manipulation ( &(*t)->next[x] ) from C to C#

Tags: c#, c, pointers

I am trying to convert some old 'C' code to C#, but having a  problem with the syntax `t = &(*t)->next[u];` and `(*t)->end = 1;`

The relevant part of original code is as follows

```
typedef struct Trie Trie;

struct Trie {
    int end;
    Trie *next[26];
};

void trie_insert(Trie **t, const char *p)
{
    while (*p) {
        unsigned u = trie_index(*p++);
        if (u < 26) {
            if (*t == NULL) {
                *t = calloc(1, sizeof(**t));
            }

            t = &(*t)->next[u];  // how to convert this??
        }
    }
    if (*t == NULL) {
        *t = calloc(1, sizeof(**t));
    }
    (*t)->end = 1;
}

Trie *trie_from(const char **data)
{
    Trie *t = NULL;

    while (*data) {
        trie_insert(&t, *data++);
    }

    return t;
}
```

and my converted code (so far) looks like this

```
class Trie
{
    int end { get; set; }
    public Trie[] next;

    public Trie()
    {
        next = new Trie[26];
    }
    public Trie(string[] data)
    {
        Trie[] t = null;
        foreach (string cc in data)
        {
            insert(t, cc);
        }
    }
    void insert(Trie[] t, String p)
    {
       foreach (char c in p) { 
            UInt32 u = index(c);
            if (u < 26)
            {
                if (t[0] == null)
                {
                    t[0] = new Trie();
                }

                t = &(*t)->next[u]; // how to convert this line??
            }
        }
        if (t[0] == null)
        {
            t[0] = new Trie();
        }
        (*t)->end = 1; // and this line??
    }
```

any help with these lines (and anything else I have done wrongly!) would be most welcome.

There's also a Trie comparison function in the C Code:

```
int trie_cmp(const void* pa, const void* pb)
{
    const void* const* a = pa;
    const void* const* b = pb;

    return (*a > *b) - (*a < *b);
}
```

which I have converted as follows:

```
public int CompareTo(Object obj)
        {
            Trie that = (Trie)obj;

            for (int n=0; n< 26; n++)
            {
                Trie t1 = this.next[n];
                Trie t2 = that.next[n];
                if (t1 == null && t2 == null)
                    continue;
                if (t1 == null)
                    return -1;
                if (t2 == null)
                    return +1;
                if (t1.end || t2.end) {
                    int foo = 1;        // debug point
                }
                return (t1.CompareTo(t2));
            }
            return 0;
        }
```

but debugging shows that every Trie referred to is NULL (the code never gets beyond `if (t1 == null && t2 == null)  continue;`)

If it helps to know, the data used for the Trie structure is a large array of 5-letter words (always 5 letters).

I did try a free version of a commercial C++ to C# converter, which wasn't helpful.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38915212).

Comment: In other words, for your purposes, `t` and `&(*t)` are essentially equivalent.

Comment: A string in c language is an array of consecutive characters ending with a '\0'.  The while loop is taking up to 26 characters and putting into string.  So you can declare a string t and then add characters to the string with a plus sign : t += 'a';  The code you are having issue with is just moving the pointer to the next character which the foreach is already doing.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Not really, in this case, the address being taken is that of `next[u]`. The lack of parentheses makes this confusing.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Your "duplicate" has nothing to do with this question, as was already mentioned. This wouldn't even compile if this was "equivalent" as you said.

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265825. "Convert code from one language to another" is not a well-defined task. It's clearer to explain in your own words specifically where you are encountering a problem, and specifically what that part of the code needs to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand from the question that the algorithm is not necessarily to be implemented line by line in C#, but rather mutatis mutandis.

Since the instance var `end` indicates that the end of a word has been reached, it would therefore be in C# rather of type `bool` and not `int`.

Assuming that there are methods in the class Trie that encapsulate access to internals, this variable could also be made private and the name adjusted to `_end` appropriately.

```
private bool _end;
```

The main concern of this question is to define a tree node structure. The program has an array of nodes where each element can be either `null` or point to the next node. The goal is to establish a tree-like structure for strings composed of an alphabet, such as a-z. This requires an array of 26 nodes, with each position corresponding to a character in the alphabet. This approach enables identification of common prefixes, which can be useful for features like autocompletion.

An graphical example for the array of words `new[]{"intranet","interstate","indecisive","intense"}` would look like this:

[image: example structure]

Each end of a word is marked with a `*` in the graph.

A good explanation of tries can be found [here](https://datastructures.maximal.io/tries/).

In C code the node is a struct that is dynamically allocated. The pointers to the struct are then placed at the location based on the character in the array. In C#, the equivalent would be to create a node object using the `new` keyword and assigning it to the corresponding location in the array. Note: the array is initialized to `null` references.

Accordingly the Trie `next` array could be declared like this:

```
private readonly Trie?[] _next = new Trie?[26];
```

The method `Insert` could be implemented recursively something like this:

```
private void Insert(String p)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(p))
    {
        _end = true;
        return;
    }

    var u = Index(p[0]);
    if (u < 26)
    {
        var t = _next[u] ??= new Trie();
        t.Insert(p[1..]);
    }
}
```

If you prefer a non-recursive variant, how about something like:

```
private void Insert(String p)
{
    var t = this;
    foreach (var c in p)
    {
        var u = Index(c);
        if (u < 26)
        {
            t = t._next[Index(c)] ??= new Trie();
        }
    }

    t._end = true;
}
```

For the sake of completeness, here the constructors:

```
private Trie()
{
}

public Trie(string[] data)
{
    foreach (var cc in data)
    {
        Insert(cc);
    }
}
```

You could call it something like this:

```
Trie trie = new Trie(new[]
{
    "intranet",
    "interstate",
    "indecisive",
    "intense"
});
//call some method on trie...
```

Comment: Stephan, that is most useful and things are begining to work! But in my question I originally missed out a Trie comparison method (C code now shown) which I'm having problems converting - will this need to be recursive as well, drilling down into each node to find differences? BTW I had intended to change `end` to a `bool` but hadn't got round to that yet!

Comment: I've now tried a comparison function (see revised question) but this seems to show that the Tries aren't being populated correctly, they are all NULL at the first level

Comment: Regarding `tri_cmp`: without context on how this is used, it's hard to give tips on implementation since one doesn't do pointer comparison in C#. If you run my C# example code with copy/paste and insert the example array with `"intranet"` etc. you will see that not all `_next` entries are NULL (look at `_next[8]` which corresponds to the character "i").

Comment: Thanks, I can see your example populating correctly. I need to look elsewhere in my code. The compare function is used for an array of 10 Tries, which must all be different - so they are sorted and then each compared with the next to ensure inequality. (to see what I'm doing, see the first answer at (https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119574/how-to-create-a-5-x-5-word-grid)

Comment: Done it! C# now producing the same output at original C. So I can now use the code in a .NET service, and easily change the size of word grids. Thanks again.